# Bokeh custom JS callback date range slider

Tags: python, callback, bokeh

I try to create an interactive diagram which plots values Y over dates X. So far so good. Now I want to adjust the limits xmin and xmax of my x-axis via a DateRangeSlider but I don't understand the js callback function (I want to have a standalone html file at the end) and since I don't even know how to print values from inside the function and without any errors produced, I have no idea what to do now.

here is a running example of code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, DatetimeTickFormatter, HoverTool
from bokeh.models.widgets import DateRangeSlider
from bokeh.layouts import layout, column
from bokeh.models.callbacks import CustomJS
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show, save

datesX = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=100)
valuesY = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': datesX, 'y': valuesY['A']}) 

# output to static HTML file
output_file('file.html')

hover = HoverTool(tooltips=[('Timestamp', '@x{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'), ('Value', '@y')],
                           formatters={'x': 'datetime'},)
    
date_range_slider = DateRangeSlider(title="Zeitrahmen", start=datesX[0], end=datesX[99], \
                                        value=(datesX[0], datesX[99]), step=1, width=300)

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(title='file1', x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='yValue',  x_axis_type='datetime', 
               tools="pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset", plot_width=300, plot_height=200)

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
    
p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source, line_width=2)
p.add_tools(hover)
       
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source), code="""

    ##### what to do???

    source.change.emit();
    """)
    
date_range_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
layout = column(p, date_range_slider)

# show the results
show(layout)
```

I tried to adjust and adapt similar examples of people on stackoverflow and from the bokeh demos, but i didn't manage to produce running code. Hope everything is clear and You can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a new `source.data` when changing the sliders. To do that, you also need a "back-up" `source` that you **don't** change and which serves as a reference for what data to include. Passing both as arguments to the callback function makes them available to the Javascript code.

```
datesX = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', periods=100)
valuesY = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,25,size=(100, 1)), columns=list('A'))

# keep track of the unchanged, y-axis values
source = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': datesX, 'y': valuesY['A']}) 
source2 = ColumnDataSource(data={'x': datesX, 'y': valuesY['A']})

# output to static HTML file
output_file('file.html')

hover = HoverTool(
    tooltips=[('Timestamp', '@x{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}'), ('Value', '@y')],
    formatters={'x': 'datetime'},)
    
date_range_slider = DateRangeSlider(
    title="Zeitrahmen", start=datesX[0], end=datesX[99],
    value=(datesX[0], datesX[99]), step=1, width=300)

# create a new plot with a title and axis labels
p = figure(
    title='file1', x_axis_label='Date', y_axis_label='yValue',
    y_range=(0, 30), x_axis_type='datetime',
    tools="pan, wheel_zoom, box_zoom, reset",
    plot_width=600, plot_height=200)

# add a line renderer with legend and line thickness
    
p.line(x='x', y='y', source=source, line_width=2)
p.add_tools(hover)

callback = CustomJS(args=dict(source=source, ref_source=source2), code="""
    
    // print out array of date from, date to
    console.log(cb_obj.value); 
    
    // dates returned from slider are not at round intervals and include time;
    const date_from = Date.parse(new Date(cb_obj.value[0]).toDateString());
    const date_to = Date.parse(new Date(cb_obj.value[1]).toDateString());
    
    const data = source.data;
    const ref = ref_source.data;
    
    const from_pos = ref["x"].indexOf(date_from);
    // add + 1 if you want inclusive end date
    const to_pos = ref["x"].indexOf(date_to);
        
    // re-create the source data from "reference"
    data["y"] = ref["y"].slice(from_pos, to_pos);
    data["x"] = ref["x"].slice(from_pos, to_pos);
    
    source.change.emit();
    """)
    
date_range_slider.js_on_change('value', callback)
layout = column(p, date_range_slider)

# show the results
show(layout)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I have to work this through, but it looks exactly what it should do. At the moment I have difficulties to "print" variables from inside the callback function. Do you have any hints how this works? When i open the browsers console nothing is printed there.

Comment: Glad it helped! You can only print Javascript variables from inside the callback script - like I added in the example code: `console.log(cb_obj.value);` or `console.log(data);`

Comment: it looked like what i wanted to have at first, but my next step would have been a linear trend line of visible data. setting the non-visible range to -100 is probably not the right solution then. I'll play with it, maybe I can get where I want to be.

Comment: I ran the code but I can't find the output, must be me ¯\ (ツ) /¯

Comment: It would be in the Console section of your browser's dev tools - `Ctrl + Shift + K` in Firefox or `F12` in Chrome

Comment: I finally found the output, but I don't understand why^^ I already tried this before. Also your updated code produces a blank diagram by changing the Limits.

Comment: the recreated array seems to be empty

Comment: I don't know how you created that gif, but the code you shared is not working for me. I found out, that from_pos and to_pos can't be determined like that, because they give me index -1. The determination of date_from and date_to is false. date_from must be floored to the same day, not the day before and date_to should include every hour to the next day like 2018-04-10T23:59:59.999. I don't know how to do that in Java. Also I don't know if indexOf(date_from) does the job, since ref["x"] still has time included and indexOf is fed with a timeless date. Would be great if you could give some hints!

Comment: Just tested it again using Bokeh 2.2.3 and works as advertised in Firefox & Chrome. :) As I mentioned in the code comments, just add +1 to position index if you want a different end date.

Comment: Ah I see, so there is the problem. I (have to) use bokeh 1.4.0. Can you tell me a way to work around a problem like this? How can I find out which commands can not be interpreted in an older version?

Comment: This was a really helpful answer for me! Do you think it makes sense to use a date range slider if you don't have data points for each timestamp in the date range? I run into a problem with a dataset where there is a data point for every other day. Array.indexOf won't work in that case, I used filtering on x and splicing y based on the index of the endpoints of the filtered array. The chart works but bokeh still gives me an error of source columns not having consistent length, even though when I console log their length, they are equal.

Comment: Please check the answer from @Paul Whitney below, no JS needed there!

Answer (score 2):

I found out that the answer above does not work since the timestamps of the `ref_source` data are different than the parsed timestamps which come from the bokeh Slider Object (`cb_obj`).

So for example the timestamps from the `ref_source` data create the following output when being parsed with `new Date(source.data.["x"]);`:

***01/01/2020 02:00:00***

The timestamps coming from the bokeh Slider Object `cb_obj` always have a time of ***00:00:00***. Therefore the timestamps cant be found when using `const from_pos = ref["date"].indexOf(date_from);`.

To parse the dates from the `ref_source` correctly I created a new array `new_ref` and added the correctly parsed dates to this array. However, I have to emphasize here that I am not a JavaScript expert and I am pretty sure that the code can be written more efficiently here.

This is my working example:

```js
// print out array of date from, date to
console.log(cb_obj.value); 

// dates returned from slider are not at round intervals and include time;
const date_from = Date.parse(new Date(cb_obj.value[0]).toDateString());
const date_to = Date.parse(new Date(cb_obj.value[1]).toDateString());
console.log(date_from, date_to)

// Creating the Data Sources
const data = source.data;
const ref = ref_source.data;

// Creating new Array and appending correctly parsed dates
let new_ref = []
ref["x"].forEach(elem => {
    elem = Date.parse(new Date(elem).toDateString());
    new_ref.push(elem);
    console.log(elem);
})

// Creating Indices with new Array
const from_pos = new_ref.indexOf(date_from);
const to_pos = new_ref.indexOf(date_to) + 1;


// re-create the source data from "reference"
data["y"] = ref["y"].slice(from_pos, to_pos);
data["x"] = ref["x"].slice(from_pos, to_pos);

source.change.emit();
```

I hope it helped you a bit :)

Comment: Thank you very much, finally that's the right solution. I don't know how @gherka made his gif, because only your code is doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem and discussion. Adding the following two lines (one of which was lifted directly from the documentation) allowed the slider to work without using the CustomJS and js_on_change function - using the js_link function instead:

```
date_range_slider.js_link('value', p.x_range, 'start', attr_selector=0)
date_range_slider.js_link('value', p.x_range, 'end', attr_selector=1)
```

Comment: God bless you. This should be the default answer for recent versions of bokeh. No custom JS code. Clean and neat!

Answer (score 0):

I had similar success to @Jan Burger but using the CustonJS to directly change the plots x_range rather than filtering the datasource.

```py
callback = CustomJS(args=dict(p=p), code="""
    p.x_range.start = cb_obj.value[0]
    p.x_range.end = cb_obj.value[1]
    p.x_range.change.emit()
    """)

date_range_slider.js_on_change('value_throttled', callback)
```